# One single Chapter in the middle like "Appendices" on appendixpage

Tags: page, appendix

I like to center one chaptername like the appendices at the following example, but I dont know how to handle it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6H2o.png

I thought about using \vfill, but then I think I can just center it at 50% of the page and not at ~30%.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: It depends on your document class.  However the chapter title is inside a \parbox and the "Chapter #" is outside it.  You might be able to use part instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the `\titleformat` command from the `titlesec` package but I don't know if this  fits the question.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\chapter{ A normal chapter}
\lipsum

{\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\vfill \centering\bfseries\Huge}{\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}{1cm}{}[\vfill\vfill\vfill\clearpage]

\chapter*{A vertically (\(\sim 30\% \)) centered chapter}}
\lipsum
\chapter{Another normal chapter}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]